# How focus on the document after find?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, google-docs, google-spreadsheets

I'm filling a column after finding a row via a search on the name column. So I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, type the name, and click the the cell with mouse to fill it. Is there a way to do this without using the mouse?

Although that would be great, it doesn't have to jump to the cell I'm editing. I can use the arrow keys but I cannot set the focus on the document with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find and you find the one you want (press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to cycle through them), press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and you'll have control and focus in the selected cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *Find and Replace* as well in the *Edit* of the Google Spreadsheet, by pressing <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>:
[image]

Enter the string you're looking for and once found, you can enter the replacement string:
[image]